# compile dll to work in other languages

Tags: c#, dll

Is it possible to compile c# dll in a way that it can be imported in different programming languages or does it work only with visual studio projects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [ComVisible] attribute allows C# code to be used in practically *any* language that can run on Windows.  COM support in a language runtime was pretty mandatory to give a language a chance to be adopted on Windows.  You'd of course use whatever tooling is available for the language, it doesn't require VS.

Comment: So for example a dll compiled in c# will work in for example dev shed c++?

Comment: As long as you write proper COM client code in your C++ project, yes, no problem.  The C++ language isn't exactly the friendliest kind for this kind of task.

Answer (score 4):

It will work with any .Net language (VB.Net, F#, IronPython etc). You don't need Visual Studio. You can use other IDEs like SharpDevelop, or even your favourite text editor plus a command shell to compile your code.

There are also interop possibilities with non .Net languages via bridging components like this one for java:

http://www.jnbridge.com/